# Retrieving Emails from Office365 using OAuth2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, imap, azure-ad-msal, mailkit

I am looking for a complete **Step-by-step** to accomplish the following objective.  I have been looking around and trying many, many ways, but not one of them works.

**Objective:**  using C# .net core code (in Azure Functions) connect to a **shared mailbox** of Office 365 to retrieve emails [with date filter] to do some processing, then move that email from Inbox into another folder (Processed).  I want to use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (or something similar
that is free and has MIT license) to retrieve, load and parse the emails.

What I have done, but of course, I can be way off…

- In **Azure Active Directory**, I have created an App Registration
- In **API Permissions**, I have added and granted (I am an admin) a lot of permissions (everything I guess may be related to this, from
  Email, to IMAP, SMTP, POP, Application, User and a bunch of other permissions.
- In **Certificates & Secrets**, I created a client secret and recorded the secret (Value)
- From **Overview**, I recorded the Client ID, Tenant ID, etc.

**Code** (I tried several variation of this…)

```
string[] scopes = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
/*
   for scopes, I have also tried:
      “https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All”
      “https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All” 
*/

var authority = authority + tenant;
/* 
   for authority, I have also tried:
      “https://login.microsoftonline.com/“
      “https://login.microsoftonline.com/common”
      “https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2”, etc… 
*/

var client = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientID)
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority)) 
    .Build();
 
/* Fails every time! */ 
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;
var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

/* MailKit to retrieve emails… */
/* 
   any step-by-step code using MailKit to 
   accomplish the Objective would be much appreciated.
*/
```

Comment: Have you seen and tried following the guide at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md ? It *should* help you get it working.

Comment: Yes, and I keep getting this error:  Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details

Comment: Make sure to copy the exact same scopes that appear in the HOWTO. Your scopes are not the same. Using the code from the HOWTO, it works for me.

Comment: Yep, I tried it exactly like that, but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: @user13971889 Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not use this method to get the access token.

```
var client = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientID)
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority)) 
    .Build();
```

This method is using client credential flow which is not supported to use `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permission.

This [method](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md#authenticating-with-oauth2) mentioned by **jstedfast** is using [Interactive provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider). The interactive flow is used by mobile applications (Xamarin and UWP) and desktops applications to call Microsoft Graph.

So if [configuring "http://localhost" as a Public client (mobile & desktop) redirect URI for your application](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-4#app-registration) doesn't work, I don't think you could implement it in the C# .net core Azure Function app. Azure Function app doesn't support login interactively within it. You can only use it in a console app.

But there are 2 workarounds which allow you to get the user access token for Microsoft Graph.

1. Implement [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider) to generate the client and access token. But it is using [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) which is not recommended by Microsoft. See details on **Warning** tip.
2. Configure additional Login Params in App service to get the access token to call Microsoft Graph. Please refer to [CONFIGURING AN APP SERVICE TO GET AN ACCESS TOKEN FOR AAD GRAPH API](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/02/configuring-an-app-service-to-get-an-access-token-for-graph-api/). The key point is changing the **additionaloginparams** to the following `[“response_type=code id_token”, “resource=https://graph.microsoft.com”]`. Related official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#limit-the-domain-of-sign-in-accounts).

Comment: Any ideas what might be causing a similar problem I'm having here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72775465/4631427 ?

Comment: In case someone is interested in an ROPC solution, I made a post about it with code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984691/how-to-use-mailkit-with-imap-for-exchange-with-oauth2-for-daemon-non-interacti/72984692#72984692